# In VueJs3 why can't I access data properties from the vue object? (it worked in Vue2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

### Background

I've been using Vue 2 for a long time and am currently exploring Vue 3 to see what converting our existing website will entail.  Because this is a conversion I plan to use the options interface for Vue 3.  For the most part it seems like the conversion should be fairly painless.  But I have encountered one Vue3 behavior that I find very puzzling.

### Vue 2 Example

In Vue 2 if I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Vue2 app.variable example</h1>

    <!-- vue template -->
    <div id="appTemplate">
        <div style="margin-bottom:20px">Count: <span v-text="count"></span></div>
        <button v-on:click="increment()">Increment</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Vue2 Example 
        var app = new Vue({
                el: '#appTemplate',
                data: {
                    count: 101
                },
                methods: {
                    increment: function() {
                        this.count++;
                    }
                },
                created: function(){
                    _app = this;
                }
            });

        alert("app.count is:" + app.count)

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, the alert looks like this:

[image: vue 2 app.count alert]

This demonstrates that after the vue object is created I can access the data properties as though they hang directly off of the `vue` object.  This is as expected since it's documented behavior.

## However, Vue 3 Behaves Differently for Me

Here is a block of analogous Vue3 code with a bit of extra code you will probably notice:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Vue3 app.variable example</h1>

    <!-- vue template -->
    <div id="appTemplate">
        <div style="margin-bottom:20px">Count: <span v-text="count"></span></div>
        <button v-on:click="increment()">Increment</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Vue3 OptionsAPI 
        var _app;
        var app = Vue.createApp({
                data: function() {
                    return {
                        count: 101
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    increment: function() {
                        this.count++;
                    }
                },
                created: function(){
                    _app = this;
                }
            }
            
        );
        app.mount("#appTemplate");

        //It's really odd that we can't access the property this way:
        alert("app.count is:" + app.count);

        //but this works.
        alert("_app.count is:" + _app.count);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When this page loads and the first alert box is shown, `app.count` is undefined.

[image: Vue 3 app.count alert]

To explore this a bit more you can see in the code that I set the value of an `_app` variable to the value of `this` in the `created` method.  And I show a 2nd alert on load that displays `_app.count`.  And sure enough that works and displays the correct value:

[image: Vue3 _app.count alert]

So that's pretty interesting.  Is it by design in Vue 3 data properties can't be accessed directly from the vue object or is something wrong with my code?  It seems like a really big change from Vue 2 if it's by design.  So I'd like to hope that it's not.

**So here is the question:** Why can't I access `count` via `app.count` after the `var app = Vue.createApp` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vue 2, `new Vue()` returns the root component.

In Vue 3, `createApp()` returns the [application instance](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#the-application-instance), and the [root component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#the-root-component) is returned from the application instance's [`mount()`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mount):

```js
var app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 101,
    }
  }
})
     
var root = app.mount('#appTemplate')
console.log(root.count) // => 101
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Vue3 app.variable example</h1>

    <!-- vue template -->
    <div id="appTemplate">
        <div style="margin-bottom:20px">Count: <span v-text="count"></span></div>
        <button v-on:click="increment()">Increment</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Vue3 OptionsAPI 
        var app = Vue.createApp({
                data: function() {
                    return {
                        count: 101
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    increment: function() {
                        this.count++;
                    }
                },
                created: function(){
                    _app = this;
                }
            }
            
        );
        var root = app.mount("#appTemplate");

        alert("root.count is:" + root.count);


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could chain the `mount()` call off of `createApp()`:

```js
var app = Vue.createApp().mount('#appTemplate')
console.log(app.count) // => 101
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Vue3 app.variable example</h1>

    <!-- vue template -->
    <div id="appTemplate">
        <div style="margin-bottom:20px">Count: <span v-text="count"></span></div>
        <button v-on:click="increment()">Increment</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Vue3 OptionsAPI 
        var app = Vue.createApp({
                data: function() {
                    return {
                        count: 101
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    increment: function() {
                        this.count++;
                    }
                },
                created: function(){
                    _app = this;
                }
            }
            
        ).mount("#appTemplate");

        alert("app.count is:" + app.count);


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **This** is exactly why I love `StackOverflow`.  Such an excellent short answer that throws light on the underlying change in a way that makes perfect sense, and the solution obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You could also access that property before mounting the app  :

```
 app._component.data().count
```